# Как правильно обработать данную строку?

Tags: javascript

Есть строка:

```
asdasd@asd.ru:sdfjsf\r\nasdasdasd@asdasd.ru:jsdgj\r\nasdashsdfh@asdasd.ru\r\nfhksdfjhsdfjh@asd.ru:djhsdfj
```

Ее нужно обработать с помощью js, чтобы после обработки она была в виде массива, где будут лежать данные для каждой строки в таком виде:

```
[
    {'email' : '1email', 'password' : 'adgshs'},
    {'email' : '1email', 'password' : 'adgshs'}
]
```

Как это сделать? 
Понимаю, что это, скорее всего, нужно делать с помощью split, но не понимаю, как :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

как-то вот так:

```js
var str = 'asdasd@asd.ru:sdfjsf\r\nasdasdasd@asdasd.ru:jsdgj\r\nasdashsdfh@asdasd.ru\r\nfhksdfjhsdfjh@asd.ru:djhsdfj';
var object = str.split('\r\n').map(function (val) {
    var obj = val.split(':');
    return {email: obj[0], password: obj[1]};
});
console.log(object);
```